# How to determine received signal strength including reflections?

Tags: rf, signal, antenna

I have an RF system with known transmit power, transmit antenna gain, receive antenna gain, distance, and frequency (900MHz ISM band).

I can calculate direct received signal strength based on those parameters alone, but how does that change with surface reflections? I can easily figure out the incidence angle, but how do I calculate the resulting signal strength as a superposition of the two waves?

Comment: That would all be theoretical, because you can't predict the exact spot of everything in the real world.  Moving the TX or the RX or any reflectors by a centimeter invalidates your calculations.  And how much the reflection matters is dependant on the strength of the incident wave and the reflected wave.

Comment: I'm not looking for an exact precise measurement, but rather a general baseline to work off of. Just a simple model of transmitter at one height, and a receiver at another height a certain distance away over various surfaces like groundsoil, sand, and water.

Comment: you are asking to define the "glint" of a system, which depends  very strongly upon surface conductivity and roughness and frequency and angles.

Comment: Superposition can make the signal stronger or weaker depending on the phase. At 900MHz the phase will vary 'randomly' so while the signal strength may be higher the 'surface reflections' should be considered interference rather than signal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation